# Azure Storage Queue: vs2013 shows queue as empty although peek shows a message while debugging from local machine

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have a strange problem.  When I perform a peek on my storage queue, it shows there is a message on the queue after I insert the message.  However, if I use the server explorer and drill down to the queue and view contents the queue appears empty.

I have breakpoints set on the code I expect to pull the message off of the queue but it is never called.  Also, if I use the server explorer to add a new message to the queue.  It seems to disappear a few seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a queue, insert a message, and then view a recently added queue via the server explorer in storage emulator. If you are using storage emulator, please make sure you are checking at the right place in the server explorer tree.  Browsing and Managing Storage Resources with Server Explorer article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683677.aspx has more information.  If you are still having issue, please post your sample code.